# How to use rawQuery() with a WHERE clause to find a specific date from a given column?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a query as mentioned below, but I am getting the cursor to return 0 when I use the `getCount()` function on the Cursor.

Please help me to get my query written properly.

```
String DT_Value = SetAlarm.Today_Date;
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from NAME WHERE DATE= " +DT_Value ,null);
return c;
```

My `DT_Value` value was `16-08-08` and that value is available at the 4th column of my table NAME, but when I call the function `c.getCount()` I am getting the count as 0.

Comment: How did you verify that the value is in the database? And is the column named `DATE` for the `NAME` table?

Comment: `My DT_Value value was "16-08-08"` Then your timestring is wrong. It should be `"2016-08-08"`. And mind the single quotes enclosing string values (or use bound parameters). For your reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: I have the function to view my db, so i found that value in db

Comment: I have formatted the date value from 2016-08-08 to 16-08-08 with the below function                                                                                      public static String Today_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd").format(new Date()).toString();

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution it is as below

```
 String[] params = new String[]{ Today_Date };
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE DATE =  ?", params);
return c;
```

Thanks Guys...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use modified query

```
Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from NAME WHERE DATE='"+DT_Value +"'",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor getuser(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String qry = "Select * from UserDetails where name ='" + name + "';";
    Cursor c     = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
        return c;

}
```